# Matplotlib Animation Blurry When Output From Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I create an animated graph using matplotlib's FuncAnimation, the axis ticks and labels are blurry when I use Jupyter Notebook, as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsOmG.png). This is not the case when I use Python from the console.

Here is a minimal working example that has this problem when I run it from a Jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

the_plot, = ax.plot([], [])  # Empty array for initialisation

ax.set_xlim(np.min(x), np.max(x))
ax.set_ylim(np.min(y), np.max(y))

def update(i):
    the_plot.set_data(x[:i+1], y[:i+1])

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, range(len(x)), save_count=len(x))
anim.save('Out.mp4', fps=25, writer='ffmpeg')
```

Comment: I see the same thing when I use your code in sessions launched from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/ffmpeg-python-binder). (Used `%conda install numpy matplotlib` in the session to add the extra needed.) **HOWEVER**, your code run in sessions launched from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder) produces crisp output.  (Used `%conda install ffmpeg` in the session to add the extra needed.) It's not the JupyterLab vs classic because I tried from both in both sessions. I think it may be the ffmpeg version/associated codecs that `apt` installs vs conda. Maybe?

Comment: I neglected to point out in my comment above that I was only running from inside notebooks. (The underlying Python in both is 3.7.12  and IPython only differs by 7.33.0 vs. 7.32.0. And classic notebook was 6.4.12 vs 6.4.10. So all pretty similar in those regards.) I don't quite know what my finding mean for solving it for you; however, I think my findings most likely signal that something aside from Jupyter as the culprit. It may be in your situation a difference in the environment that Python has vs. Jupyter?

Comment: Did you try setting the dpi of the figure explicitly?

Comment: @JodyKlymak I tried this, it does not make a difference.

Comment: @Wayne Thanks for your exploration of this issue. I did find a fix, though not an explanation: in my notebook, I had the magic command `%matplotlib inline` at the top. When I removed this, the axis ticks rendered as desired.

Comment: Hmmm...that's interesting but in my tests I avoided any inclusion of `%matplotlib` at all when running your code. But the differences I saw may point to differences in how the backend rendering is getting set behind-the-scenes. You seemed to be adjusting it explicitly. I think with what we both found we have some different ways to try to come at a solution. Different versions of software or try the `%matplotlib inline`.